# How can I access SVG elements in html (with CSS preferably) without pasting the code in directly?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I was trying to work through [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) as a practice for a bigger project I'm working on.
My actual SVG is really big, so I would rather not just copy paste the whole giant code directly into HTML.

But here's the practice one I made (i'm also not sure how to clean SVGs made in Inkscape, but I deleted some of the stuff that didn't seem necessary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg1"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="49.595489 30.040314 84.135223 84.305336"
   height="84.305336mm"
   width="84.135223mm">
  <path class="path5076"
     id="path5076"
     d="m 70.303571,78.340773 c -4.032971,0.006 -8.033187,1.698025 -10.862132,4.572387 -2.828946,2.874362 -4.455685,6.891674 -4.445904,10.924637 0.0095,3.927963 1.572604,7.841853 4.315065,10.653953 2.74246,2.8121 6.641232,4.47709 10.569138,4.45364 4.633366,-0.0277 9.108311,-2.43049 12.384652,-5.70683 3.574526,-3.57453 6.411017,-6.242046 9.347584,-9.825986 0,0 7.17598,-6.918764 10.743336,-10.51178 3.56737,-3.593016 7.41006,-7.169152 11.08478,-10.843875 3.34645,-3.346446 6.32139,-6.581106 9.51049,-9.812482 3.3753,-3.420038 5.15813,-7.12199 5.18334,-11.661986 0.0216,-3.889398 -1.60848,-8.155743 -4.38434,-10.880165 -2.77587,-2.724421 -6.6563,-4.279784 -10.54572,-4.261811 -3.8759,0.01791 -7.72562,1.595418 -10.48769,4.314587 -2.762056,2.71917 -5.002206,6.149863 -4.776456,11.428746 -0.0484,4.514439 2.874106,9.098792 5.148056,11.372746 3.19237,3.192372 6.9848,6.227335 10.17717,9.419709 3.20164,3.201638 6.0452,5.990107 9.58187,9.526778 1.80732,1.807321 3.93629,5.149881 4.68721,7.593023 0.75092,2.443141 1.01197,5.054051 0.5999,7.576553 -0.55185,3.378163 -2.33545,6.072793 -4.93781,8.296363 -2.60235,2.22358 -5.80201,3.69214 -9.22483,3.7206 -4.69281,0.039 -9.04011,-1.51725 -12.0905,-4.81311 -3.187696,-3.44421 -7.211206,-7.037566 -10.268806,-10.463896 -3.057595,-3.42633 -6.28628,-6.607684 -9.408672,-9.762441 -3.174881,-3.207791 -7.386446,-5.316042 -11.899731,-5.30936 z"
     style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#febc00;stroke-width:10.80000019;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />

</svg>
```

In the tutorial it says:

> Let's target the path with CSS (assuming we're using inline SVG here,
>   or via an 'object')

which is great because just uploading svg without copy-pasting is exactly what I wanted. But I'm not sure how to proceed now. From what I could find, the only way to access the inside parts of SVG is through javascript, which I've never done before as I don't know javascript.

So I have this

```
<object id="svg1" data="path.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to access the path inside the SVG.

I tried putting in this code that I found, but it didn't do anything.

```
<script>
    window.onload=function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("svg1");
    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
    var svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("path5076");
    svgItem.setAttribute("fill", "lime");
};
    </script>
```

I then found someone saying that I had to let the SVG load first, so I added

```
<script>
    var mySVG = document.getElementById("svg1");
 var svgDoc;
 mySVG.addEventListener("load",function() {
      svgDoc = mySVG.contentDocument;
      alert("SVG contentDocument Loaded!");
 }, false);
    </script>
```

but that also didn't seem to work.

This is my first stab at JS, so any help is appreciated.
But if you know how this can be done with CSS **PLEASE** let me know, I'm much more comfortable with it (as comfortable as I can be after two weeks of learning it, as opposed to 0 weeks with JS)

---

Edited as per suggestion, but I think I'm still doing it wrong.

Also, I only left `"fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#febc00;stroke-width:10.80000019"` in `style` and removed everything else. Does that mean I can still assign attributes like `stroke-dasharray` or do they have to be predefined inside `style` first?

[image]

still hoping someone has some other input

Comment: "Does that mean I can still assign attributes like stroke-dasharray". Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The style precedence, from lowest to highest, is

1. attributes
2. CSS style sheets
3. inline styles

Your SVG uses inline styles (*style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;...*).

So your code is correct but no matter what you do with the "fill" attribute, it is overridden by the inline style, so *svgItem.setAttribute("fill", "lime");* is useless.

You need to alter the inline style somehow.
The easiest solution is to change the inline style by calling:

```
 svgItem.setAttribute("style", svgItem.getAttribute("style").replace("fill:none;","fill:lime;"))
```

but you can also remove the inline style completely and work with the attributes/external CSS instead.

another option is to convert inline style to attributes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("svg1");
    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
    var svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("path5076");
    // replace inline style with attributes
    var styleText = svgItem.getAttribute("style");
    svgItem.removeAttribute("style");
    for (let pair of styleText.split(';')) {
     let [key, value] = pair.split(':');
     svgItem.setAttribute(key,value);
    }
    // now you are ready to work with the attributes
    svgItem.setAttribute("fill", "lime");
};
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that about style precedence. Thanks for letting me know. I tried your code but for some reason the attributes still don't get reassigned.

Also, what do you mean by "work with the attributes/external CSS "? I thought you guys said I can't edit attributes with CSS when uploading svg as `object`